# class loader in rampart fail to find PWCBHandler

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

I have a web service client inside a webservice develop in axis2.
the web service client need some rampart dependencies to construct the soap message and also need the password for the user.

the passwork are taken from this class:PWCBHandler and I put this class inside the web service that contain the web service client to another webservice.

and rampart load that class from the policy in this way

```
rc.setPwCbClass(PWCBHandler.class.getName());
```

the problem its that rampart cannot find the class at this code line:

```
    Class cbClass;
    try {
        cbClass = Loader.loadClass(classLoader, cbHandlerClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RampartException("cannotLoadPWCBClass", 
                new String[]{cbHandlerClass}, e);
    }
```

My question is: where I need to put this class to load it from rampart config??

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem fixed, the class loader search for the jars in [tomcat]\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\classes\ so as a work around I create a .zip with the .class inside and rename to .jar and ir work. :-D